# Pytube error (pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError) while making a YT video downloader, think it is realted to tkinter

Tags: python

```
  File "C:\Users\박찬은\PycharmProjects\ytvidget.py", line 19, in <module>
    GetInpBtn1 = tk.Button(text = "다운로드", command=ptubeget())
  File "C:\Users\박찬은\PycharmProjects\ytvidget.py", line 8, in ptubeget
    video_url = YouTube(link)
  File "C:\Users\박찬은\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
  File "C:\Users\박찬은\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 133, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
  File "C:\Users\박찬은\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*

Process finished with exit code 1

My Code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube

def ptubeget(): # Function to download YT video
    link = GetInp1.get() # Getting YouTube video link
    video_url = YouTube(link) # Downloading YT video
    video_url.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
    return 0 # Ending the function

root = Tk() # Tkinter
root.geometry("300x95") # Screen size
root.resizable(0, 0) # Not resizable
root.title("YtVidGet") # Title
Lbl1 = tk.Label(text="YtVidGet", font="Arial")
Lbl2 = tk.Label(text="YouTube Downloader")
GetInp1 = tk.Entry()
GetInpBtn1 = tk.Button(text = "Download", command=ptubeget())

Lbl1.pack()
Lbl2.pack()
GetInp1.pack()
GetInpBtn1.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

I'm making a Python YouTube Video downloader, and I keep get this error. I think this is something related with tkinter since if I make this code Command Line Interface-only, it works without any issues. I have no idea why it's giving me a error. Can someone help me please?